# Question about polar coordinates in relation to $x^2-y^2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I was reading about polar coordinates, and I know that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, however, what is the polar coordinate equivalent to $x^2 - y^2$?

Comment: Well, you know expressions for $x$ and $y$ in polar coordinates. What do you get?

Comment: So it would just be rcos(theta)^2 - rsin(theta)^2 = r^2(costheta^2 - sintheta^2), is there no way to simply this even more?

Comment: Nope. You can use a double angle formula if you are so inclined.

Comment: could you multiply r^2(costheta^2 - sintheta^2) by negative 1 to get -r^2(1)?

Comment: You'd better work on your basic algebra skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in polar cordinate, you have $$\left\{\begin{align*}x&:=&r\cos(\theta)\\ y&:=&r\sin(\theta)\end{align*}\right.$$where $r\in \mathbb{R}^{+}, \theta\in [0,2\pi)$.

Now, you have $$x=r\cos(\theta) \implies x^{2}=r^{2}\cos^{2}(\theta)$$and $$y=r\sin(\theta) \implies y^{2}=r^{2}\sin^{2}(\theta)$$Then, you have for example $$x^{2}-y^{2}=r^{2}(\cos^{2}(\theta)-\sin^{2}(\theta))\overbrace{=}^{\cos^{2}(\theta)+\sin^{2}(\theta)=1}=r^{2}(1-2\sin^{2}(\theta))\overbrace{=}^{1-2\sin^{2}(\theta)=\cos(2 \theta)}r^{2}\cos(2\theta).$$

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand.

Comment: Are you sure about $3 \theta $?

Comment: @zkutch I read the question wrong. I already corrected

Comment: @Ramanujan: No, you didn't read it wrong. But you should review your double angle identities. They're double-angle, not triple-angle.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I already corrected.